# Condition to check uploaded files before displaying them (Protecting uploaded files)

Tags: python, django

I've got a simple Django model as described below:

```
class UploadedFile(models.Model):
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    uploaded_file = models.FileField(upload_to=file_upload_directory, validators=[ValidateUploadFileSize])
```

and I handle upload of files via a class based view which works fine. When users upload files it successfully gets uploaded to the server directory. When the user accesses the file via an anchor tag, the URL looks something like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/444131/module/24.pdf`. What I want to know is how do I do some validation *before* opening the file based on some condition that decides whether to display or not display the file?

Let me expand on this. In the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/444131/`, `444131` is an ID for an object in the database. I want to be able to check if the current user belongs to that object. If the user exists in that object, then I want to display the file, otherwise, I'd like to do some kind of redirect or not show the file. This is to prevent any random person from being able to brute force the urls or prevent accidental file discovery.

I've been thinking of using middlewares but I'm not entirely sure if that is the right way to do it? I've also tried to match the urls by creating a pattern in the `urls.py` files but that doesn't work. The issue I'm facing with that is after the pattern has been matched, I have no way of actually displaying the file. If I did end up displaying the file, users would most likely be able to play around with the urls and just get into other uploaded files.

The way I'm doing that is as below:

```
urls.py
--
 re_path(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/module/(?P<file_name>[\w.]{0,256})$', views.DisplayFile.as_view()),

views.py
--
class DisplayFile(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Condition to check if the request.user can view or not.
        pass
```

What is the best way to approach this issue?

EDIT: For clarity sake, I'm trying to protect uploaded files so that it's only accessible by those who belong to the object.

Thanks. 
Ahmed.

Comment: I think this is too broad. It sounds like a design issue more than anything else.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I've made a small edit to say that I'm trying to protect uploaded files that are only accessible by those who belong to the object. If you have any suggestions, feel free to answer.

Comment: @AhmedCader Have you thought about hashing the URL with their username? That way you can prevent people from snooping id incrementally. Also, upon the request, you can verify that the hash matches the username.